# cdk : how to stop generating random suffix in nested stack name

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I am using CDK with Python where I have a nested stack with a fixed id/name calling a custom construct also with a fixed id/name. Why does it still get a random string generated at the end of the name still? Is there no way to stop it?
[image]

The custom construct is creating a DynamoDB table and due to the random suffix generated at the end of the stack name, the stack fails when it runs the second time saying table already exists. I need the table to be created with a retain policy so don't want it deleted every time the stack is executed. The table name also has to be consistent and can't change to include any random autogenerated string. The name for the table comes from a configuration fed into the stack which is referenced in an application elsewhere that I can't modify.

Here is the nested stack code

```
from aws_cdk import (
    NestedStack,
)
from myconstructs import StepFunctionConstruct


class MyInfraStack(NestedStack):

    def __init__(
        self,
        scope: Construct,
        construct_id: str,
        **kwargs,
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        sf_const = StepFunctionConstruct(
            self,
            id="dev-StepFunctionConstruct",
            state_machine_name="dev-sf"
        )
```

This is custom construct code

```
class StepFunctionConstruct(Construct):

    def __init__(
        self,
        scope: Construct,
        id: str,
        state_machine_name: str
    ):
        super().__init__(scope, id)

        # code here to create dynamo db table
```

How to get rid of the circled in red suffix from the image above when deploying this stack?

Comment: Please describe the expected and observed deploy behaviour.  Is the random stack name suffix unexpectedly changing between deploys?

Comment: That is odd. I don't think the nested stack should get renamed like that automatically.

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example with the entire code? Have you done `cdk destroy`? In your construct, you're passing a non-existent prop (`state_machine_name`) - the code shouldn't synth. Also, the construct ID is not the resource's name - the ID being static doesn't prevent the generation of a physical name with a hash.

Comment: @gshpychka: that non existent prop was a typo. corrected it. So how do you prevent the generation of a physical name with a hash? I thought a static id would be sufficient.

Comment: @fedonev: yes, the random stack name suffix changes at every deploy. Even if I pass in the id which is a fixed string.

Comment: Have you done cdk destroy? What do you mean by every deploy? Can you provide a code example we could synth?

Comment: @gshpychka: yes I have done a cdk destroy. It doesn't destroy the DDB tables, which is fine - it needs to be that way. I am talking about a scenario where anytime I make any sort of changes in the stack and deploy, it fails because now the stack has a different random string attached to its name which makes it a new stack, but then its trying to create the same DDB table with the same name. The DDB table name can't change and needs to stay fixed. This gives the error - resource already exists. I will try to paste the full code after cleaning it up soon.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

The Stack name doesn't change on any update. Moreover, that's not the issue here.

Also, the construct ID isn't the resource name, it being static doesn't mean the name will be. Read more in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/identifiers.html#identifiers_construct_ids).

Here's what's happening here:

1. You deploy the stack, it's created with an auto-generated name.
2. The stack deploys a DDB table with an explicitly specified name and a retention policy of `Retain`, meaning it is not deleted on stack destruction.

If you deploy the stack again with any changes at this point, the stack's name will not change.

3. Then you destroy the stack, but the table still exists due to the retention policy.
4. You deploy the stack again, the stack's auto-generated name changes. That's not the issue, though - the issue is that it's trying to deploy a DDB table with an explicitly specified name, but it cannot do that because a table with that name already exists.

Even without destroying the stack between deploys, you can run into this issue if you introduce a change to the DDB resource that requires replacement. The way CloudFormation handles replacements is by first creating the new version of the resource and then deleting the old one. But it cannot create the new version, because the name would be the same.

This is why it's recommended to let CloudFormation generate the names for you (like you do for the stack).

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html